# Can't find .js files in Chrome Sources tab?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

Thanks for giving this question a look.
I'm an absolute newbie in JavaScript and just tried to learn JavaScript yesterday so my knowledge about this is pretty low. (Sorry for my bad English)

I tried to run a .html file with a .js file included in it but when i ran it with Live Server Extension, I can't see the .js file in the Page tab in Sources and I can't execute the .js file too. All I see is the index.html file. Is there any solution for this, guys?

[This is my page with the Inspector turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MviN.png)

[These are my files displayed in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4j7z.png)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>This is the title.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>So this is the header</h1>
    <script scr='home.js'>
        alert('something')
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And home.js

```
alert('Do you see me?');
```

My file structure is very simple

```
2nd
├── home.js 
├── index.html
```

I've tried to

- Search a lot on Stack Overflow
- Change the directory of the .js file
- Create a sub-folder and put the .js file inside to make the .html above it(or lower the .js)

But still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're serving only the index.html file not the whole directory. You could try to run Live Server from the root directory (which is `2nd` in this case) or check out this npm package for setting up a simple http server https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

P/s: There is a typo in your script tag, `src` not `scr`

Answer (score 1):

The script should be loaded in HTML like this:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the source line at the end of the body tag. This will work, I believe.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>This is the title.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>So this is the header</h1>


    <script scr='home.js'>
        alert('something')
    </script>

    <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```